# Unique number for unique visitor on button click in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How generate the unique no. 1,2,3 and so on .... on button click of each new user ..

the code mentioned below is a  readwrite coding in vb.net ...

but the problem is it generate the same id for different users on button click event... but i want the no. of times button clicked the new ids will be generated

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = Server.MapPath("counts.vbi")
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
            objWriter.Write(Literal1.Text)
            objWriter.Close()
        Else
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = Server.MapPath("counts.vbi")
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objStreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Literal1.Text = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd
            Literal1.Text += 1
            objStreamReader.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  You have a unique SessionID if you are using ASP.Net for each user in case you want to do some calculation based on userid...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Random Id like this :

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
```

Hope This can Help You.

Thanks